# Is it possible for the main function to be a friend of a class?

Tags: c++

I know that this is detrimental to data hiding but theoretically is this allowed ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course.

`main` is an almost completely ordinary function.

Comment: `main` is not *completely* ordinary. For instance, it may not be called from anywhere in code.

Comment: Not only `main` cannot be called from anywhere, it *cannot* be overloaded also.

Comment: Friend declarations have the side effect of, well, being a declaration. That is, they do declare the function that you are befriended in the enclosing scope (or the fully qualified scope), so I thought that might be problematic. On the other hand, I have rechecked the standard, and what is forbidden is to *define* more than one `main` function (there is no mention to declarations), so it seems to be ok. At any rate, you will have to befriend all variants of `main` that might be used in programs that use your class: `int main()`, `int main( int, char** )`, `int main( int, char**, char** )`

Comment: @David, I've never encountered the last variant. What's the purpose of the second `char**`?

Comment: @rcollyer it's `envp`, the environment variables, described in the C99 standard in `J.5.1/1` as a common extension.

Comment: @rcollyer: It is common in VS and it is used to contain the environment variables. In general an implementation is allowed to accept any variant as long as it at least accepts the two most common.

Comment: @David and @Cubbi, I haven't used VS in years (7+), so I guess that is why I hadn't encountered it.  Thanks.